# How to properly configure this Camel route xml?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, routes, apache-camel

I'm trying to build a somewhat-fancy Camel route using Camel's XML `<camelContext>`.

I have two ActiveMQ queues, `toProcess` and `ready`, and a MySQL database. The database has a `widgets` table that looks something like this:

```
widget_id | widget_name | widget_value
(INT)       (VARCHAR 50)  (INT)
```

An external process places raw String messages on the `toProcess` queue. These messages are simple Strings such as:

- "*fizz*"
- "*buzz*"
- "*foo*"

etc. I want to poll this `toProcess` queue every 5 minutes (using Camel-Quartz) and incorporate the Strings found in the bodies of these consumes messages (fizz, buzz, etc.) in a JDBC `SELECT` statement that looks up any `widgets` whose `widget_name` matches String (such as fizz or buzz).

*Then*, I want to take every `widget` record retrieved from the JDBC call and place it on the `ready` queue. Finally a `Burninator` bean should consume from `ready` and pass each `Widget` POJO to its `Burninator#burninate(Widget)` method.

So to recap:

1. External process places a String such as "fizz" on the `toProcess` queue
2. Camel-Quartz job fires every 5 minutes and dequeues "fizz" (and any others)
3. Camel-JDBC `SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE widget_name = 'fizz'` --> I suspect I'll need XPath
4. Say 25 `widget` records are returned by query
5. All 25 get serialized (binary/JSON/XML?) and place on `ready` queue
6. One by one, `Burninator#burninate(Widget)` dequeues `ready` and executes with the next dequeued widget

Here's what I've got so far, but I know it's wrong:

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>com.myapp.bus</package>
    <template id="camelTemplate"/>
    <route>
        <from uri="quartz://toProcessPollerJob?cron=*+5+*+*+*+?"/>
        <to uri="activemq:toProcess"/>
        <setBody>
            <constant>
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    widgets
                WHERE
                    widget_name = ??? (e.g., fizz, buzz)
            </constant>
        </setBody>
        <marshall>
            <serialization/>
        </marshall>
        <to uri="activemq:ready"/>
        <unmarshall>
            <serialization/>
        </unmarshall>
        <to uri="bean:burninator?method=burninate"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Can any Camel wizards point me in the right direction here (besides reference the chapter in *Camel in Action* that I should read ;-) ). Specifically I'm having trouble:

- Parameterizing the JDBC SQL with the appropriate String value for `widget_name`
- Serializing whatever the JDBC SQL returns to something that can get sent to the `ready` queue
- Deserializing the messages on the `ready` queue into a Java `Widget` POJO

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some other languages than constant, as thats just a constant.
For example simple, groovy or even a template language like velocity etc.
Where you create the SQL to use.

Try with

```
<simple>
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                widgets
            WHERE
                widget_name = '${body}'
</simple>
```

Can you see the supported languages here
http://camel.apache.org/languages

Or use a template framework such as Velocity or Freemarker to generate the SQL based on a template file.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this code snippet, because I worry about SQL injection... Unless camel-jdbc has things in place to stop SQL injection?